# in Python and linux how to get given user's id

Tags: python, linux

There is os.getuid() which "Returns the **current** process’s user id.". But how do I find out any given user's id?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use [`pwd.getpwnam()`](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html#pwd.getpwnam):

```
In [5]: pwd.getpwnam('aix').pw_uid
Out[5]: 1004
```

Answer (score 38):

Assuming what you want is the username string associated with the userid for your program, try:

```
import os
import pwd
pwd.getpwuid( os.getuid() ).pw_name
```

Use os.geteuid() to get the effective uid instead, if that difference matters to you.

Use pw_gecos instead of pw_name to get the "real name" if that's populated on your system.

Answer (score 7):

[`pwd`](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html):

```
import pwd
for p in pwd.getpwall():
    print p

pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='_calendar', pw_passwd='*', pw_uid=93, pw_gid=93, pw_gecos='Calendar', pw_dir='/var/empty', pw_shell='/usr/bin/false')
pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='_teamsserver', pw_passwd='*', pw_uid=94, pw_gid=94, pw_gecos='TeamsServer', pw_dir='/var/teamsserver', pw_shell='/usr/bin/false')
pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='_update_sharing', pw_passwd='*', pw_uid=95, pw_gid=-2, pw_gecos='Update Sharing', pw_dir='/var/empty', pw_shell='/usr/bin/false')
pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='_installer', pw_passwd='*', pw_uid=96, pw_gid=-2, pw_gecos='Installer', pw_dir='/var/empty', pw_shell='/usr/bin/false')
pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='_atsserver', pw_passwd='*', pw_uid=97, pw_gid=97, pw_gecos='ATS Server', pw_dir='/var/empty', pw_shell='/usr/bin/false')
pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='_ftp', pw_passwd='*', pw_uid=98, pw_gid=-2, pw_gecos='FTP Daemon', pw_dir='/var/empty', pw_shell='/usr/bin/false')
```

Answer (score -5):

You could just parse `/etc/passwd`, it's stored there.

Comment: It might be stored there, or in NIS, or in LDAP, or in any other source for which there's an nsswitch module. That's why we have APIs that start with `getpw` — so that you don't have a bug because you parsed `/etc/passwd` by hand on a system that uses (say) NIS to store user information.

Comment: mkj: Thanks! Didn't know about NIS and LDAP.